# How can I get gradle to rename an intermediate file?

Tags: android, build, gradle, zipalign

In my `build.gradle` file, I have the following:

```
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
      def oldFile;
      if (variant.zipAlign) {
        oldFile = variant.outputFile;
      } else {
        oldFile = variant.packageApplication.outputFile;
      }

      def newFile;
      def newFileReplacement = "";

      if (getVersionName().indexOf(gitSha()) != -1) {
          newFileReplacement = newFileReplacement + "-" + getVersionName() + ".apk";
      } else {
          newFileReplacement = newFileReplacement + "-" + getVersionName() + "-" + gitSha() + ".apk"
      }

      newFile = oldFile.name.replace(".apk", newFileReplacement);

      if (variant.zipAlign) {
        variant.zipAlign.outputFile = new File(oldFile.parent, newFile);
      } else {
        variant.packageApplication.outputFile = new File(oldFile.parent, newFile);
      }
    }
```

When I run the following command: `./gradlew clean assembleRelease`, it creates the following .apk files for me:

```
MyApp-release-1.2.3-e1ad453.apk
MyApp-release-unaligned.apk
```

(`MyApp-release-1.2.3-e1ad453.apk` is zipaligned, but the other one is not)

What I *want* it to create are the following files:

```
MyApp-release-1.2.3-e1ad453-unaligned.apk
MyApp-release-1.2.3-e1ad453.apk
```

Where `MyApp-release-1.2.3-e1ad453-unaligned.apk` is not zip aligned, and `MyApp-release-1.2.3-e1ad453.apk` is zip aligned, since that seems to be the way that gradle operates by default (i.e. it adds to the name of the file that isn't aligned, rather than adding to the name of the file that *is*).

Basically, what appears to be happening is that the rename functionality operates **before** files are actually created, and just specifies the output file I supposedly want. This is fine, but is it possible to also specify what I want the intermediate file `MyApp-release-unsigned.apk` to be **before zipAlign** runs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get gradle to rename the intermediate file by using `variant.packageApplication.outputFile`:

```
    // This next part renames the .apk file to include the version number
    // as well as the git sha for the commit from which it was built.
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
      def oldFile;
      if (variant.zipAlign) {
        oldFile = variant.outputFile;
      } else {
        oldFile = variant.packageApplication.outputFile;
      }

      def newFile;
      def newFileReplacement = "";

      if (getVersionName().indexOf(gitSha()) != -1) {
          newFileReplacement = newFileReplacement + "-" + getVersionName() + ".apk";
      } else {
          newFileReplacement = newFileReplacement + "-" + getVersionName() + "-" + gitSha() + ".apk"
      }

      newFile = oldFile.name.replace(".apk", newFileReplacement);

      if (variant.zipAlign) {
        // Set the name of the final output file
        variant.zipAlign.outputFile = new File(oldFile.parent, newFile);

        // Set the name of the intermediate file (input to zipAlign) to contain version
        // information, too
        def oldIntermediateFile = variant.packageApplication.outputFile
        def newIntermediateFile = variant.packageApplication.outputFile.name.replace(".apk", newFileReplacement)
        variant.packageApplication.outputFile = new File(oldIntermediateFile.parent, newIntermediateFile)
      } else {
        // Set the name of the final output file (no intermediate file)
        variant.packageApplication.outputFile = new File(oldFile.parent, newFile);
      }
    }
```

What's going on here is that if **zipAlign** is disabled, then `variant.packageApplication.outputFile` will be the resulting file that's created. If **zipAlign** is enabled, then `variant.packageApplication.outputFile` will be the intermediate (unaligned) file that's created, and `variant.zipAlign.outputFile` will be the final (aligned) file that's created. So, I'm getting zipAlign to use a differently named file by changing the name of **both** `variant.packageApplication.outputFile` **and** `variant.zipAlign.outputFile`.

**One final note for posterity**:

In case you make the same mistake I made, I originally tried:

```
    variant.zipAlign.outputFile = new File(oldFile.parent, newFile);
    variant.packageApplication.outputFile = new File(oldFile.parent, newFile);
```

but, this doesn't work because then the unaligned file name and the aligned file name have the same name, and zipAlign will refuse to align a file into itself (i.e. it must have an output file name that is different from it's input file name).

Comment: Very useful. Just a quick comment: in Android Studio 1.0 we have to loop through the variant outputs instead of just the variants:`applicationVariants.all { variant ->variant.outputs.each { output ->`.

Comment: In fact you can simply refer to `variant.outputs[0].outputFile` which will either equal `variant.outputs[0].packageApplication.outputFile` or `variant.outputs[0].zipAlign.outputFile` depending on whether zipAlign is enabled.